# meaning of "place" in openmp and parallel computing

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I am a newbie in openmp and parallel computing. Now I am studying OMP_PLACES. So what is the meaning of "place"? Why we need "place" and what is the use of "place"?
I have checked the openmp specification but i still do not know what is "place".
Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OMP_PLACES` variable is sophisticated. Usually `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` is enough, but for more control you can

1. set `OMP_PROC_BIND=close` or `spread` to determine wether threads should be placed close together on cores/sockets, (setting `spread` mostly is relevant to multi-socket systems) and then
2. set `OMP_PLACES=cores` or `sockets` to indicate whether the close/spread pertains to cores or sockets. Setting to `cores` is best for cache behavior because a thread stays tied to a core. Setting to `sockets` means the OS can move threads about for load balancing, but that destroy L1 cache locality.

There is also a mode where `OMP_PLACES` is explicitly spelled out in terms of core numbers. That one is nigh incomprehensible.

Comment: The last mode can be useful when the binding is non trivial. For example, when one want to use only 1 socket (so to analyse NUMA effects) while not having thread migration between cores. Indeed, `OMP_PROC_BIND` only prevent threads not to move between places but not within processing-units belonging to the same place. The same is true for people wanting to avoid migration between hardware threads of the same core or to use only few cores per NUMA node (eg. to study the memory throughput). hwloc can be used to generate such a list since writing it manually is quite insane on many-core systems.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Your point happily granted.